# convert nanoseconds since 1904 to a valid java date

Tags: java, date

I have a number representing the number of nanoseconds since 12:00 a.m., January 1, 1904, universal time. I wish to instantiate a `java.util.Date` object representing that date. How should I proceed?

Comment: Wouldn't be the number changing like anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You first need to convert your *number* representing *nanoseconds* to *milliseconds*.

Then for the given date string, get the total number of milliseconds since the unix time *Epoch*, and then add the number earlier converted to milliseconds to it.

Here's the working code:

```
String target = "1904/01/01 12:00 AM";  // Your given date string
long nanoseconds = ...;   // nanoseconds since target time that you want to convert to java.util.Date

long millis = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(nanoseconds, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS); 

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm aaa");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = formatter.parse(target);

long newTimeInmillis = date.getTime() + millis;

Date date2 = new Date(newTimeInmillis);

System.out.println(date2);
```

Add an `import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;`.

Comment: The date format should be in UTC timezone, and not in default timezone.

Comment: You also forgot calendar system, which is locale dependent, my answer is more precise.

Comment: @kan: a number of millis is a number of millis. That is not locale nor calendar dependant.

Comment: @JBNizet He-he. Just change your default locale to Japanese and observe the bloody fireworks. Moreover, this solution is more verbose and dirty, e.g. you need try-catch block.

Comment: I have tried this method but it returns the same date for two different values for the nanoseconds field, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Marcio. What fields you took? Please make sure there is enough difference between them to make significant difference in date.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is trivial:

```
final GregorianCalendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
startDate.clear();
startDate.set(1904, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
final long startMillis = startDate.getTimeInMillis();
new Date(nanos / 1000 / 1000 + startMillis)
```

Comment: And Timestamp.valueOf() uses the current timezone, and not UTC.

Comment: @BalusC Honestly I don't think there is a way to use jdk date/time functions which would not be abuse... Always beter to use Jodatime.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, you are right about timezones. The proper solution is to use gregorian calendar, which is not default tz, locale, specific.

Comment: @dispake Don't worry. My first answer revision was using Timestamp class instead of calendar.

Comment: this method also returns the same date for two different nano values eg 3457619519760815616L and 3457619519767058432L

Comment: @Marcio No, why? It is 2013-07-25T18:51:59.760 and 2013-07-25T18:51:59.767 accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Date date = new Date(new Date().getTime()-(time in nanoseconds/(1000*1000)));

what's wrong in using this? I tested with a value of "time in nanoseconds" for June 8th 1926 and it works. and date format has nothing to do with it, the underlying milliseconds value representing the time is what is required.

Comment: Your solution is simply wrong. Your solution does not reference the date Jan 1st 1904 in any way, but the result needs to depends on this date. Otherwise, your solution would be universal for other time systems, too, like nanoseconds since May 5th 1850 (just an arbitrary made up date). Moreover, you have a minus in front of your "time in nanoseconds", which has the effect that the later the time in nanos is, the earlier your Date object's time will be. Moreover, your result depends on the current time. That make it a total of 3 mistakes in this rather short formula.

Answer (score -3):

First of all `java.util.Date`

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the **nearest millisecond**.

So, if you have variable `milliseconds`

1. Somehow calculate number of milliseconds between your date and Jan 1, 1970 (Unix epoch) `diff`
2. Use `Date(long)` constructor

   ```
   new Date(milliseconds - diff);
   ```

Comment: Isn't step 1 basically "here, a miracle happens"?

Comment: just thought that if date is fixed, we can do it in "magic" way (known for OP for example)